# Preference issue, how to save an int between runs?

Tags: java, preferences

My prefence keep resetting, what am I doing wrong?

```
Preferences prefs;
final String PREF_NAME;
public int testValue;

public ClassTest()
{
    prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(ClassTest.class);
    PREF_NAME = "name_of_preference";

    if(prefs.getInt(PREF_NAME, testValue) == 0)
    {
        testValue = 500;
        prefs.putInt(PREF_NAME, newValue);
    }
}
```

I want it to be so that when user runs the program it look if it's set or not(0). If it's not set then it sets it to 500. I then restart my program and for some reason testValue still has the value 0 instead of just skipping the if-statement. Anyone know what I am doing wrong or got a better idea on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: There is a `flush()` method to ensure changes are written to the backing store.  Normally you wouldn't be required to do this manually however - so it's not the answer to your question.

Comment: How do you "restart" your program?  Are you letting the first program terminate, or are you running it while your first process is still running?  The javadoc says "Normal termination of the Java Virtual Machine will not result in the loss of pending updates -- an explicit flush invocation is not required upon termination to ensure that pending updates are made persistent".  But if if the JVM isn't terminating normally, the changes may not have taken hold.

Comment: @ajb I click the exit button and make sure that the program is closed before I run it again.

Comment: Does the exit button use System.exit() or does it let the main() terminate? BTW +1 for prefs.flush() or alternatively, prefs.sync()

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the exit button. I heard from someone that you could use another class, something like "seizable" or something in that style. Do you guys know what I mean? It's like a class which got the same purpose but saves the object or something.